# Mostar datos Correctos del paciente

Tags: php, sql, pdo, condiciones, foreach

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de agendas de turnos donde al mostrar el turno se muestra el nombre del paciente, los tratamientos y esas cosas, lo que quiero hacer es que al darle click en el nombre del paciente me muestre un modal con sus datos como por ejemplo(Nombre,Apellido,Cedula,Telefono,etc).

El modal lo tengo echo el tema es que cuando le doy click en el nombre no me muestra los datos de ese paciente sino que me muestra otros datos de otro paciente para mostrarles:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Acá muestro con el modal los datos pero no son del paciente que clicke:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero que haga es que cuando se habrá el modal me muestre los datos de ese paciente no de otro, ósea que muestre los datos del paciente que le doy click, les paso el codigo que tengo echo para eso:

```
        $x = 0; 
       while ($x < 25) {
         
        $turnosFiltrados = array_filter($turno, function ($dato) use ($hora_s, $x, $sucursalDrop, $PROfesional, $fecha) {
          
            return ($dato->HORA_INICIO == $hora_s[$x]) && ($dato->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL == $sucursalDrop) && ($dato->FECHA == $fecha) && ($dato->PROFESIONAL == $PROfesional);
            
        });
        
        
        
        if ($turnosFiltrados) {
         
            $dato = current($turnosFiltrados);
         
            $sql2="SELECT * FROM pacientes WHERE CEDULA_PACIENTE = $dato->CEDULA_PACIENTE";
            
            ?>
            <tr style="background:#dc35451f;">
         
            <td style="width:7%; margin-left: 10px;"><strong><?php echo substr($dato->HORA_INICIO, 0, -3);?> a <?php echo substr($dato->HORA_FINAL, 0, -3); ?></strong></td>
            <td style="width:50%; margin-left: 10px;">
            <input type="checkbox"  id="btn-modal2" value="">
                  <label  id="<?php echo $dato->CEDULA_PACIENTE ?>"  >[ <strong >Paciente:  </strong><label for="btn-modal2" class="lbl-modal2" style="color: blue;text-decoration-line: underline;"><?php echo $dato->NOMBRE_PACIENTE  ?></label> ]</label>
                  <div class="modal2">
                    <div class="contenedor2">
                      <header>Ficha Paciente</header>
                     
                      <label for="btn-modal2" style="position: absolute; color: white;"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></label>
                      <div class="contenido2">
                      
                      <div class="text-center" style="font-size: 20px; margin-top: 5px;"><strong><?php  ?> <?php   ?></strong></div>
                      <br>
                      <div><strong>Cedula: </strong><?php  ?></div>
                      <br>
                      <div><strong>Telefono: </strong><?php  ?></div>
                      <br>
                      <div><strong>Direccion: </strong><?php  ?></div>
                      <br>
                      <div><strong>Correo Electronico: </strong><?php  ?></div>
                      <br>
                      <table class="table table-bordered bg-light text-black">
                        <thead>
                          <th>Foto Antes</th>
                          <th>Foto Despues</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                        <td><img src="<?php  ?>" alt=""></td>
                        <td><img name="fotodespues" src="<?php  ?>" alt=""></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br> [  <strong>Tratamiento: </strong><?php echo $dato->TRATAMIENTO ?> ] [ <strong>Zona: </strong><?php echo $dato->ZONA ?> ]
                 [ <strong>Equipo: </strong><?php echo $dato->EQUIPO ?> ]
```

Ahora es verdad que capas lo que estoy haciendo esta mal, me refiero al foreach pero alguien me podría ayudar con eso y decirme como puedo hacerlo para que funcione?? o si no se puede hacer con el foreach con que otra función podría hacerlo?? les doy las gracias desde ya, muchas gracias.

Comment: primero el modal se llama igual en todos los casos por ende no importa que modal le des clic abrira siempre el mismo modal.... aparte el enfoque esta mal pero como estas empezando solo con corregir ello te funcionaria. una opcion seria darle "modal".$id asi todos variarian... lo mejor es utilizar `ajax` o `fetch()`

Comment: como puedo usar fetch() ?? :0

Comment: claro que es el mismo modal porque lo que quiero se cambie solo es los datos del paciente no el modal

Comment: si pero los modals tienen una referencia para saber cual abrir si todos les pones el mismo nombre todos haran referencia al mismo.. :V [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) y el propio modal trae una opcion [ajax](https://jquerymodal.com/#example-4)

Comment: mmmmmm el tema es que mi modal esta echo por css xd y como se usa eso de fech y ajax bro??

Comment: te agrage los lin a ambos para que puedas observar de que se trata....
ya que de la forma que lo intentas deberas crear un modal para dato... eso haria tu pagina extremadamente pesada....

Comment: aaa recién veo gracias lo voy a estar mirando

Comment: Lo de ajax esta bueno eso de llamar al modal y agregarle funciones pero como lo agregaría a mi código eso es lo que no se xd